# How to get memory usage in Rails app.?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory

For example, I have Update action in Product Controller.
I want to measure how much memory consumption when the Update action being invoked.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

New Relic's RPM will do what you need -
http://www.bestechvideos.com/2009/03/21/railslab-scaling-rails-episode-4-new-relic-rpm

also take a look at some of the answers here: [ruby/ruby on rails memory leak detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161315/ruby-ruby-on-rails-memory-leak-detection)

Answer (score 0):

[Ruby Memory Validator](http://www.softwareverify.com/ruby/memory/index.html) monitors memory allocation for Ruby applications.

If you want to modify your Ruby runtime to add a memory tracking API to it, take a [look at this](http://www.softwareverify.com/ruby/customBuild/index.html).