# rails memory usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memory, profiling

I'm using a hosting, where I have 60MB RAM

My Rails3 app is using 63MB RAM.

I want to optimize it, but How I can find out, what code part takes most memory ?

Comment: that doesn't solve the problem, How should an bigger hosting find out what eats most memory ? Read more carefully the questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on your rack middleware, but I'm not sure.

Plugins which helps you to log your memory usage on Github:
Oink, MemoryLogic, Bleak_house.

For sure I would try a Caching plugin! Rack-cache seems a really pure one, find it on Github.

Read this [ruby/ruby on rails memory leak detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161315/ruby-ruby-on-rails-memory-leak-detection)

Ruby Enterprise Edition may halp, but I don't know your hosting provider.
For first shot I found this for Passenger: sudo passenger-memory-stats
Have you tried hosting on Heroku?

Sorry for not giving any url, but system didn't allow me. Good luck,
gezope

Answer (score 0):

You should use a service such as [Appsignal](https://appsignal.com/) / [Sentry](https://sentry.io) / [ScoutAPM](https://scoutapm.com/) / [New Relic](https://newrelic.com/) to have a better understanding of what's happening in your production environment.