# Ruby - free up memory used by required gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory, rubygems, require

Is there a way to free up memory used by required gems? My Rails app grows in memory usage and I would like to use gems only when I need them and after that free them up, IF this is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you use Ruby Enterprise Edition? if not consider it :)

Comment: Yes, I use Ruby Enterprise Edition. However, thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of a memory managed programming language (Ruby) is to avoid developers having to concern themselves with such issues.
If memory does become a sticking point, you'll need to profile the memory by using the following tools

[ruby/ruby on rails memory leak detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161315/ruby-ruby-on-rails-memory-leak-detection)

Although your control over memory is limited to ensuring memory leaks are avoided and the overall architecture is inline with best practices. An example is ImageMagick takes excessive memory, so rather than having images being converted by all rails mongrels/passengers, restricting the conversion to dedicated ruby services, so as to avoid a large memory footprint.

Comment: Thanks. I could free up some memory by using only the libraries I needed and not including all rails app in my script, because actually that's what I have. A script instantiating rails apps.

Answer (score 0):

The Garbage Collector do it this best to you. There are no better solution. Check all part where you can have some memory leak and avoid it. Use less of gems too.