# Memory leak in Rails 3.0.5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, memory-leaks

Presently I am building application using Rails 3.0.5 on windows platform, I  am feeling some memory leak, here
is the gem details, is any of gem causing memory leak,  please let me know.

Thanks.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.5'

gem 'mysql','2.8.1' #this is compatible in both Rails 2 and Rails 3, In Windows Rails2 
mysql2 is not working

gem 'devise'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'inherited_resources'
gem "cancan"
gem 'ckeditor', '3.4.2.pre'
gem 'acts_as_versioned'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'truncate_html'
gem 'will_paginate','3.0.pre2'
gem 'permalink_fu'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem "meta_where"
gem "nested_set"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem 'redcarpet' # this will allow user to write link, add paragraph in comments on particular post
gem "userstamp"

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm','3.1.1'
end
```

Comment: Have you tried the techniques listed in this SO answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/161886/191221